# In SwiftUI, can I override a method returning some View

Tags: swiftui, view, extension-methods

in SwiftUI (using Xcode 15.1), I am trying to write a builder class that create some views, than I could extend to build some different views but Xcode doesn't consider the overwritten method as not overwriting anything.

For example, this code does compile where, from my understanding, it should fail saying B.build2 is extending A.build2 and therefore should have the override keyword.

```
class A {
    func build() {}
    func build2() -> some View { Text("A") }
}

class B: A {
    override func build() {}
    func build2() -> some View { Text("B") }
}
```

And of course, when I instantiate B and call build2, I end up with a "A" instead of "B".

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Presumably you are going to return different types of views in different `build2` implementations? This is not how views in SwiftUI should be created. You should rethink your design. SwiftUI views should not be created dynamically (without knowing the actual type of the view at compile time) like this. I suggest going through Apple's [SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) to see how to use SwiftUI properly.

Comment: You should watch “Demystify SwiftUI” SwiftUI has very specific requirements to maintain efficiency.

Comment: View structs are lightweight values on the memory stack designed to be created many times over, it makes no sense to wrap them in heavyweight classes on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any View` instead of `some View`. because `some` means the compiler should know the exact return type at the compile time, but inheritance means the sub-classed object could be used as the parent object. So it would be implemented like:

```
class A {
    func build() {}
    func build2() -> any View { Text("A") }
}

class B: A {
    override func build() {}
    override func build2() -> any View { Text("B") }
}

class C: A {
    override func build() {}
    override func build2() -> any View { TextField("", text: .constant("C")) }
}
```

Note that `any View` is not equal to `View` and you may need to type erase the result like:

```
AnyView(A().build2())
```

---

#### Another approach - Using protocol

You can use protocol to force entities have a function with their own implementation instead of inheritance like:

```
protocol A {
    func build()

    associatedtype Build2Result: View
    func build2() -> Build2Result
}

class B: A {
    func build() {}
    func build2() -> some View { Text("B") }
}
```

Comment: Despite on the correct answer using `AnyView` is a bad idea. It's better to redesign  the logic without overriding methods.